# No module named pip after installing pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to download gzip and pip was outdated. I type the following:

```
C:\Users\username>py get-pip.py
```

And then I checked if the pip was updated:

```
C:\Users\username>pip --version
pip 22.2.1 from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

But when I tried again to pip install, I got the following error message:

```
C:\Users\username>py -m pip install "gzip"
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I think I have two versions of Python and I don't know if I should delete one or not (3.8 and 3.6.1).

```
C:\Users\username>py --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: you just need to update your PATH

Comment: When you can run `pip --version` successfully, just run `pip install gzip` (without py -m)

Comment: This might be wrong, but try pip3?

Comment: `gzip` is a module included in Python's standard library — you don't need to install it. There is also a `gzip` GNU application, but you wouldn't obtain it through `pip`.

Comment: `pip` comes with Python as well.  To update it, run `py -m pip install -U pip`.  If you have multiple Pythons installed run `py -0` to list them, and `py -3.6 -m pip install -U pip` (for example) to update a specific version with `pip`.

Comment: Also it looks like you used the App Store to install Python.  I'd uninstall that one and continue using Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I had a problem after uninstalling the App Store Python. So I went ahead and downloaded the newest version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) is part of the standard library. Doesn't need installed.

---

`py` command on your PATH is coming from Anaconda. You should be able to use `conda install`, then instead.

You have two different installations of Python on your system. The one from the App Store (Python 3.8, which has `pip`), and the one from Anaconda (Python 3.6) which does not.

Ideally, you should keep/upgrade Anaconda, as it is more feature-rich, depending on your needs, and uninstall the other.

Comment: Thank you! I uninstall the Python from App Store but now I have a new error.`[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` I also tried to update the path from the environment but no success yet.

Comment: You might want to also re-install Anaconda since Python 3.6 is rather old at this point.

Comment: That's a good idea! Doing it right now.

Answer (score -1):

This means pip is not installed on the python environment you are trying to access. So in order to access a specific version of python you can try something like this:

**Python 3.6.1**

`python3.6 -m  pip --version`

**Python 3.8**

`python3.8 -m pip --version`

This should allow you to access a specific version of python and see which instance pip is being installed to.

Comment: Note: OP is using Windows, where Python documentation explicitly recommends using `py -m pip` rather than a numbered `python` exe